# Moodle 1.9 REPLACE breaks utf8_unicode_ci strings

Tags: mysql, corruption, moodle

I'm in the process of testing a Moodle site upgrade, from version 1.9 to 2.2. On a test box, I created a copy of my Moodle 1.9 site. To get the site to work on the test framework, one of the things I have to do is to update hard-coded URLs to something valid on the test machine. To do so, I use the admin/replace functionality inside Moodle 1.9, i.e.

```
http://mytestsite/admin/replace.php
```

In the resulting form, I specify which URLs to switch out. Per the documentation, the script here will then proceed to go through all tables in the Moodle installation and running a script which looks like this:

```
UPDATE adodb_logsql 
SET    PARAMS = REPLACE(PARAMS, 'some_url', 'another_url')
```

The update process seems to work fine. However, it has the following **unintended side-effect**:

Some of the content in the site, saved in the database, looks like it becomes corrupted during the REPLACE process:

```
Before: Welcome to Company’s Learning
After : Welcome to Companyâ€™s Learning
```

According to MySQL, the REPLACE statement is [multi-byte safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? A simple `REPLACE` should not have these strange side-effects.
2. Is there a simple way of undoing the damage?

Test Server: 
* IIS 7 
* PHP 5.3.13
*  MySQL Server 5.5

Comment: The same thing happens when tables are set to `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true issue here was the data export tool did not add a BOM header to the utf-8 export. During import, the importer parses a few thousand rows to check for encoding, but it never hits the rows that caused a problem, so an incorrect encoding was assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Moodle can be upgraded directly from 1.9 to 2.2, it's not 100% safe if there are huge amounts of data.

In all the recent upgrades I followed this path: 1.8 to 1.9, 1.9 to 2.0, 2.0 to 2.1 and 2.1 to 2.2. This process is tedious, but it avoids any risk in data corruption.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to follow the 1.9 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 recommended update process. The issue described in the question unfortunately happens *before* any moodle code has been updated.